# Can not close parent form when owner of non modal dialog is setted

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following code:

**FORM1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dialog dlg;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dlg = new Dialog();
        dlg.Show(this);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dlg != null && !dlg.IsDisposed)
        {
            this.RemoveOwnedForm(dlg);
            dlg.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**DIALOG**

```
public partial class Dialog : Form
{
    public Dialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Dialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}
```

I need to click twice on "X" button of form1 in order to close it. What can be a problem?

Comment: You are cancelling the close of `dlg`, why? This could be causing an issue, although it is not clear why...

Comment: I want to Hide dialog so I do not need to initialize all variables again within dialog. It is just an example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this:

```
private void Dialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}
```

This solution does not require dlg.Dispose() and this.RemoveOwnedForm(dlg) in Form1_FormClosing event.

Comment: +1 Was this  `Q & A` or after posting here you realized this?

Comment: Thought you could have explained the problem clearly if it was `Q & A` :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't try it right now, but in the Dialog_FormClosing you could add this test

```
if(this.Owner != null)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

From MSDN docs on [RemoveOwnedForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.removeownedform.aspx):

> The form assigned to the owner form remains owned until the
>   RemoveOwnedForm method is called. In addition to removing the owned
>   form from the list of owned form, this method also sets the owner form
>   to null.

Comment: It does not work. When user tries to close Form1(owner), owner tries to close all child forms (owned forms). In child form (dialog) I cancel FormClosing event and owner also cancel FormClosing event.